# What is return -1 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, return

What is the `return -1` on the third to last line of the below code? How does it work and what is its use?

```js
function findElement(arr) {
    let right_sum = 0, left_sum = 0;
    
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        right_sum += arr[i];
        
        for (let i = 0, j = 1; j < arr.length; i++, j++) {
            right_sum -= arr[j];
            left_sum += arr[i];
            
            if (left_sum === right_sum) {
                return arr[i + 1];
            }
        }
        
        return -1; // what is this?
    }
}
```

Comment: When the correct element is not found in the array, it returns -1 to indicate it. Otherwise, it returns the number that is inside the array at the correct element

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems to be simulation of native [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) `indexOf` method. It returns `-1` too, if no matches found.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the developer of that piece of code decided to return -1 if the for loop failed to return a value for error checking.

Its common for people to do these kinds of returns as it helps with error handling.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` operator is used to return a value from inside a function, so the code `return -1;` makes the `findElement` function return the value `-1` (negative 1) if the `for` loop doesn't work. This is useful for debugging. If the `for` loop works, then the function will return `arr[i + 1]`.